# Package manager for dependencies in project

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

I'm pretty sure I opened a package manager for dependencies by mistake some time ago.

Is there a package manager in WebStorm, which let you see your dependencies and let you update them + your package.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find integration with npm in *Preferences - Languages and Frameworks - Node.js and npm*.
WebStorm would list all local and global dependencies and allow you to install more from there.

There's also a bunch of related inspections available in WebStorm 2016.1: for example, if you write a require statement for a node module not installed or listed in your project package.json file, WebStorm will suggest you to install it.